# How to specify array keys from a map

Tags: php, arrays, higher-order-functions

I need to construct an array that have custom keys based on another array.

Algorithm idea:

```
  $list = [10, 20, 30];

  $map = array_map(function ($item) {
    return [
      $item => 'banana' . time(),
    ];
  }, $list);
```

What I would **expected** `$map` to be:

```
  [
    10 => 'banana 12345',
    20 => 'banana 12346',
    30 => 'banana 12347',
  ]
```

What (obviously) `$map` is:

```
  [
    0 => [
      10 => 'banana 12345',
    ],
    1 => [
      20 => 'banana 12346',
    ],
    2 => [
      30 => 'banana 12347',
    ],        
  ]
```

How to specify the array keys for this situation?

Comment: Have you thought about using array_reduce? Seems the logic choice given your requirements?!

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstood your requirement. I've couple of approach.Here both should work for you.

**1st Approach**(Mine)

```
$keys = [10, 20, 30];
$initials = 'banana'
$time = time();
$array = array_fill_keys($keys, $initials." " .$time);
print '<pre>';
print_r($array);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [10] => banana 1514305494
    [20] => banana 1514305494
    [30] => banana 1514305494
)
```

**2nd Approach** (Yours)

```
$list = [10, 20, 30];
$time = time();
$map = array_map(function ($item) use ($time){
    return [$item => 'banana ' . $time];
  }, $list);

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($map)) as $k=>$v){
    $singleDimension[$k]=$v;
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($singleDimension);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
    (
        [10] => banana 1514305494
        [20] => banana 1514305494
        [30] => banana 1514305494
    )
```

Comment: no, actually I'm using a custom laravel collection method called "mapWithKeys" that works exactly how I need.

Comment: Ok. got it. Mine was generic answer. User proper tag while you ask question at SO. best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_fill_keys` function

```
$list = [10, 20, 30];
$arr = array_fill_keys($list, 'banana');
```

Update

```
$list = [10, 20, 30];

$map = array_map(function ($item) {
            return 'banana' . time();}, 
         array_fill_keys($list));
```

Comment: Updated question. Actually, the values aren't the same on every map application. Your solution still works on this scenario?

Comment: No, it fills only the same values. Use usual loop to make array. Or create array with values and use array_combine